# MySQL Partition using column LIKE values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, rank, partition-by

I've a below table in MySQL called "test".

```
data        value
ABC>1234    5678
ABC>2345    2435
ABC>3456    4567
DEF>4567    5656
DEF>5678    7535
DEF>6789    7983
GHI>7890    6748
GHI>8901    2973
GHI>8901    3024
```

Now I wish to partition the table based on first keyword till greater than symbol (>) in the data field and wish to get RANK().

In order to achieve this, I'm running below query.

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `data`) FROM `test`
```

After running the above query, I'm getting below output.

```
data        value   RANK()
ABC>1234    5678    1
ABC>2345    2435    1
ABC>3456    4567    1
DEF>4567    5656    1
DEF>5678    7535    1
DEF>6789    7983    1
GHI>7890    6748    1
GHI>8901    2973    1
GHI>8901    3024    2
```

But desired output should be as mentioned below.

```
data        value   RANK()
ABC>1234    5678    1
ABC>2345    2435    2
ABC>3456    4567    3
DEF>4567    5656    1
DEF>5678    7535    2
DEF>6789    7983    3
GHI>7890    6748    1
GHI>8901    2973    2
GHI>8901    3024    3
```

Kindly help to get the desired output.

Comment: What value are you sorting by to get your desired rank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample data and output imply you want this query:

```
SELECT *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '>', 1)
                 ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '>', -1), value) rnk
FROM test;
```

That is, the partition is defined by the first three characters of the data, and the rank order is determined by the final four digits, or, should there be a tie, the tie would be broken by the value.

Answer (score 0):

Semms you need a partitioning due to non-numeric part, and ordering due to numeric part and `value` column for the cases with ties for equal numeric parts.

If your DB version is `10.0.5+`, then you can use `'[^0-9]+'` and `'[0-9]+'` patterns to extract those substring parts from the `data` column. So, consider using as an option :

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY REGEXP_SUBSTR( `data`, '[^0-9]+' ) 
              ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR( `data`, '[0-9]+' ), value) AS RANK
  FROM `test`
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=cfcfbd852371e08899c57c5e6c4afda9)</kbd>

Comment: It is not necessary that string after greater than symbol (>) will always be numeric.

Comment: well, please explain with expanded sample data set what you need more. Btw, what's your DB's version @BARUN ?

Comment: The sample data set can be anything and not specific to numeric or non numeric. However, they will have only greater than symbol by which we can split them and take the first part into consideration. Version is 10.5.3